# Is there a better way than doing multiple queries in my case?

Tags: php, laravel

I start in laravel and I would like to have your opinion on one point.

I have a controller. In this controller, I return a view and several functions that are all SQL queries.

My view must have all these queries because I display different types of foreach. Is this the right way to do or is there something shorter / more appropriate?

My controller :

```
 protected function indexWeb()
{
    return view('pages.web.program', [
        'getAllCoursesBloc1' => $this->getAllCoursesBloc1(),
        'getAllCoursesBloc2' => $this->getAllCoursesBloc2(),
        'getAllCoursesBloc3' => $this->getAllCoursesBloc3(),
        'getWebCoursesBloc1' => $this->getWebCoursesBloc1(),
        'getWebCoursesBloc2' => $this->getWebCoursesBloc2(),
        'getWebCoursesBloc3' => $this->getWebCoursesBloc3(),
        $this->setMetasIndex()
    ]);
}

protected function getAllCoursesBloc1()
{
    $courses = Course::where('bloc', 1)
                     ->OrderBy('title', 'ASC')
                     ->get();
    return $courses;
}

protected function getAllCoursesBloc2()
{
    $courses = Course::where('bloc', 2)
                     ->OrderBy('title', 'ASC')
                     ->get();

    return $courses;
}
... and so on
```

An exemple of foreach in my view

```
@foreach($getWebCoursesBloc1 as $key => $course)
    <tr class="link-row" data-href="{{ $course->slug }}">
        <td class="program-table__orientation">{{ $course->orientation }}</td>
        <td class="program-table__course">
            <a href="{{ url('cours/'.$course->slug) }}" class="program-table__course__link">
                <span class="program-table__course__name">{{ $course->title }}</span>
            </a>
            <span class="program-table__course__desc">{{ $course->shortdescription }}</span>
        </td>
        <td class="program-table__hour"><span>{{ $course->duration }}</span></td>
        <td class="program-table__ects"><span>{{ $course->ects }}</span></td>
        <td class="program-table__quad"><span>{{ $course->quadrimester }}</span></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Thank you very much

Comment: You should separate queries from controller. For eg. move them to model or if you use repository layer, you should put them there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use whereIn() in Laravel's model.

```
public static function getAllCoursesByIds(array $ids)
{
    return self::whereIn('bloc', $ids)
        ->orderBy('title', 'asc)
        ->get();
}
```

In controller you can get access by:

```
public function indexWeb()
{
    return view('pages.web.program', [
        'all_courses' => Course::getAllCoursesByIds([1,2,3,4,5]),
    ]);
}
```

Otherwise you can filter them by specific ids. In your view call $all_courses.

To get the Courses with "block" equals 1 use:

```
$all_courses->filter(function ($course, $key) {
    return $course->bloc === 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're realizing is that all these DB calls are currently synchronous and there is no dependency between them. In theory, if you could call them asynchronously, the script would run quicker because it's rendering as soon as the last item returns.

To do this, you need to do the rendering in the client (javascript) instead of the server. [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or [Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) would probably work best. Ultimately your client would make all the async calls to your laravel based web service and once they're all completed it would render. You may find, that you don't even need to wait for all of them and the rendering can be asynchronous as well.

You could possibly accomplish this using only PHP with something like [ReactPHP](https://github.com/reactphp).